# Populating Lightning:select with aggregate result in apex

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm very familiar with populating selectoption lists with aggregate queries in Apex and using those for drop downs in Visualforce (example below), but I'm trying to understand how to do this in a Lightning component.  I've googled looking for examples but I'm not finding any.

Thoughts?

```
public String selectOption {get; set;}

public SelectOption[] getOptions() {
    SelectOption[] options = new SelectOption[] {};
    for (AggregateResult ar : [
            select Name n
            from Contact
            group by Name
            order by Name
            ]) {
        String n = (String) ar.get('n');
        options.add(new SelectOption(n, n));
    }
    return options;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at [`lightning:select`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:select/documentation) documentation, it utilizes HTML `option` to render the select values.

> This component uses HTML `option` elements to create options in the dropdown list, enabling you to select a single option from the list.

For your particular case, as long as you can return a `List<String>`, you will be able to utilize that on your component. A typical implementation should look like as below. Note, these are only snippets, you will need to adjust it accordingly.

You modify your Apex method to return a `List<String>` as below:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> getOptions() {
    List<String> options = new List<String>();
    for (AggregateResult ar : [
            select Name n
            from Contact
            group by Name
            order by Name
            ]) {
        options.add((String) ar.get('n'));
    }
    return options;
}
```

Then you fetch the values from Apex in JS, say in the `init()` function of your component, and set the attribute.

```
var action = component.get("c.getOptions");

action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        var options = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set("v.mySelectList", options);
        ...
    }
}
```

And then utilize that on the Component:

```
<!-- this is the attribute to host the select options -->
<aura:attribute name="mySelectList" type="List" />
...

<lightning:select name="myName" label="My Label">

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.mySelectList}" var="myVal">
        <option text="{!myVal}" value="{!myVal}" />
    </aura:iteration>        

</lightning:select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response.  Exactly what I needed!